# Maven for static web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to add a wst.web facet for a multimodule maven project on eclipse. This wst.web facet is "Static web project"

You would say "why is he using maven for this?"
The point is that the whole project is a tree. I have a parent pom in the root of the project, and it has some modules, and they have their modules too. 3 levels most, for config centralising purposes and plugins and dependencies heritage.

So, one of these modules, contains 2 Static web projects, that are the UI part of other modules that are dynamic. These 2 are meant to be published in an Apache (in a Http Server within eclipse). All this already works with assembly plugin that moves stuff to target and then packs it in a tar.gz... but without the "Static web project" Eclipse does not allow me to publish it to the Http Server. I can do it by hand but that's not the point

My current config to do this is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalProjectFacets>
            <wst.web>1.0</wst.web>
            <wst.jsdt.web>1.0</wst.jsdt.web>
        </additionalProjectFacets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This is adding JavaScript 1.0 facet. But not the Static Web Project that I need

Thanks a lot for all your help.

PS: As an another reason to use maven for this, is that this tar.gz produced, is packed in a deb package, that configures the virtual host for apache, with all the AJP proxy needed to work with its backend.

Comment: What exactly is in the "tar.gz" file?

Comment: The compiled (sass) CSSs, JS, Images and htmls, ready to be published in an Apache VHost